# Windows 10 ucer cannot reach site

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, ping, traceroute

Good Morning,
I'm a noob with that and I don't know where to look for it.
Basically, a user in the network (all win10) is no able to reach a subdomain.
I've tried to do the Tracert from 2 PC (they are going out with the same public IP) and I see that the packet were killed by our provider. I don't know why... I've also tried to reset the DNS to 8.8.8.8 and *.4.4.

Basically, from the same public Address 8 PCs can connect to a subdomain.domain.com and the two remaining cannot.

What can I do? Where I can look?

I think it can be a PC settings problem (or maybe a FW problem, but we do not have static address)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Sounds like a webserver (Apache, etc) configuration problem.

Comment: Mmmm, why only for few devices? It's even possible something like that?

Comment: I see no mention of the fact, it works on other devices, only it doesn't work on a device.